# How to get average of increasing values using Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to figure out the average of increasing values in my table per column.

my table

```
 A  |  B  |  C
----------------
 0  |  5  |  10
100 |  2  |  20
 50 |  2  |  30
100 |  0  |  40
```

function I'm trying to write for my problem

```
def avergeIncreace(data,value):  #not complete but what I have so far
  x = data[value].pct_change().fillna(0).gt(0)
  print( x )
```

`pct_change()` returns a table of the percentage of the number at that index compared to the number in row before it.`fillna(0)` replaces the `NaN` in position 0 of the chart that `pct_change()` creates with 0.`gt(0)` returns true or false table depending if the value at that index is greater than 0

current output of this function

```
In[1]:avergeIncreace(df,'A')
Out[1]:  0    False
         1    True
         2    False
         3    True
         Name: BAL, dtyle: bool
```

desired output

```
In[1]:avergeIncreace(df,'A')
Out[1]:75
In[2]:avergeIncreace(df,'B')
Out[2]:0
In[3]:avergeIncreace(df,'C')
Out[3]:10
```

From my limited understanding of pandas there should be a way to return an array of all the indexes that are true and then use a for loop and go through the original data table, but I believe pandas should have a way to do this without a for loop.

what I think the for loop way would look plus missing code so indexes returned are ones that are true instead of every index

```
avergeIncreace(df,'A')
  indexes = data[value].pct_change().fillna(0).gt(0).index.values  #this returns an array containing all of the index (true and false)
  answer = 0
  times = 0
  for x in indexes:
    answer += (data[value][x] - data[value][x-1])
    times += 1
  print( answer/times )
```

How to I achieve my desired output without using a for loop in the function?

Comment: I have no idea how you get 75 for column 'A' or 10 for column 'B'. You might want to check those values. Do you mean 'C'? How does this calculation work?

Comment: @ralhlf23 10 should have been for column 'C'. The calculation I'm trying to get is the average of how much the values increase in a column when you go through the list from top to bottom

Comment: for example in column 'A' from index 0 (0) to index 1 (100) is an increase of 100 and index 2 (50) to index 3 (100) is and increase of 50 so (50+100)/2 = 75. From index 1 to index 2 is a decrease the difference between the values is not included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 100, 50, 100],
                   'B': [5, 2, 2, 0],
                   'C': [10, 20, 30, 40]})

def averageIncrease(df, col_name):
    # Create array of deltas. Replace nan and negative values with zero
    a = np.maximum(df[col_name] - df[col_name].shift(), 0).replace(np.nan, 0)
    # Count non-zero values
    count = np.count_nonzero(a)

    if count == 0:
        # If only zero values… there is no increase
        return 0
    else:
        return np.sum(a) / count


print(averageIncrease(df, 'A'))
print(averageIncrease(df, 'B'))
print(averageIncrease(df, 'C'))
75.0
0
10.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mask()` and `diff()`:

```
df.diff().mask(df.diff()<=0, np.nan).mean().fillna(0)
```

Yields:

```
A    75.0
B     0.0
C    10.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This looks like really nice, clean pandas. One question - could you also do `df.diff().mask(df.diff()<=0, np.nan).mean().fillna(0)` and skip the replace step?

Comment: You are correct @tobsecret, thank you for catching that. The `replace` is not necessary if you supply `np.nan` to the `mask()` as opposed to `0`.